# Where-Object Does not want to work with WS values

Tags: powershell

I wanted to sort all processes in `Get-Process` according to `WS` with `Where-Object`.

```
Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.WS -ge $limitas }
```

In my understanding it should get only the processes that have greater or equal `WS` value than input value `$limitas`. I hope you can give me some suggestions what I am doing wrong.

Here the rest of the code:

```
$Date = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss'    
$limitas = Read-Host -Prompt "Set the limit" # this variable sets the limit    
$procesai = Get-Process

while ($true) {    
    $Date = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss'
    $procai = Get-Process

    Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.WS -ge $limitas }  #| Out-File $outas # does not work when when I need to sort get-procceses with WS

    $outas = "C:\Users\Domantas\Desktop\powershell\atsiskaitymas\2uzduotis\outas" + $Date + ".txt"

    $kontroleris = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Domantas\Desktop\powershell\atsiskaitymas\2uzduotis" |
        Measure-Object |
        ForEach-Object { $_.Count }

    if ($kontroleris -eq 6) {
        Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Domantas\Desktop\powershell\atsiskaitymas\2uzduotis" |
            Sort-Object CreationTime |
            Select-Object -First 1 |
            Remove-Item

        Write-Host "Limitas pasiektas"
    } else {
        Write-Host "Limitas nepasiektas"    
    }

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    $i++
}
```

Comment: AFAICS the code should do what you want. What is the result you're expecting, and what is the result you actually get when you run just the statement in question? You showed your code (which is good), but didn't really describe the problem you're facing.

Comment: The displayed output `WS(K)` doesn't reflect the real values in bytes, so you might have to compare `Get-Process | Where-Object {$($_.WS/1K) -ge $limitas}`

Comment: LotPings: Thank you for your help it worked.